# Qt Graphics View: detecting collision direction

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I'm trying to create a game using qt. I have some obstacles (QPixmapItem) in a graphics view. I have a ball, and what I want is that it bounces off the obstacles. How can I detect the normal of the surface of the obstacle, so that I can calculate the new moving direction? For example:

```
------------------------------
    / \          |
   /   \         | 
  /     \        v
 /       \       ^
/         \      |
```

Comment: Perhaps you should look at the [colliding mice example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/graphicsview-collidingmice.html#id-63504b08-3dae-4482-8a2d-c636c9b358d7).

Comment: It is obvious that the sinus of angle between moving direction and the border should be the same after the ball bounced off from the border.

Comment: I've read that tutorial, and it has been very helpful. However, in that example mice turn to random direction to avoid collisions, whereas I need to calculate the angle where the ball should move after the collision.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's a math problem. Also you should use an existing 2D physics engine (e.g. Box2d) instead of inventing your own.

Comment: It's not a math problem. If I knew the angle of the normal/tangent of the surface, calculating the direction would be easy. I can only detect if a collision happens. Looking at the functions of a QGraphicsItem, shape() might be useful, but I still haven't figured out how.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, you are indeed approaching the problem correctly. What you need to get to the solution however is to iterate over the QPainterPath elements and determine which ones actually intersect with your ball's direction line(using QLineF for this should be a fairly easy task). Also, simplifying the path will reduce any bezier curves to straight lines for easier calculations(I will leave this up to you as it's not likely you will need to handle the bezier calculation yourself or possibly at all). Since there may be more than one intersection, next you will need to determine which intersection point is closest to your ball's center. Once you've figured out which point is closest, use that element in a QLineF to find it's normal vector and then you can complete your calculation of the bounce direction.

Here is some basic non-threaded code to show you how to iterate a QPainterPath and handle it's elements.

```
QPainterPath path = item->shape();

path = path.simplified(); //optional if you do not want to handle curveTo elements yourself

QPainterPath::Element element;
QPainterPath::Element P1;
QPainterPath::Element P2;
QPainterPath::Element P3;
QPainterPath::Element P4;

for(int i = 0; i < path.elementCount()-1; ++i)
{
    element = path.elementAt(i);
    if(element.isMoveTo())
    {
        //Do something
    }
    else if(element.isLineTo())
    {
        //Do something with element.x and element.y
    }
    else if(element.isCurveTo())
    {
        P1 = path.elementAt(i-1); // start point
        P2 = path.elementAt(i);   // control point
        P3 = path.elementAt(i+1); // control point
        P4 = path.elementAt(i+2); // end point

        //Do something with cubic bezier points
    }
}
```